# Jtextfield doesn't show up on launch. but after resize, yes

Tags: jtextfield

Well i need a little help. My intention of this code is to make a display of a calculator with buttons and a textfield. Im thinking of using a borderlayout where it will have a panel up north where the textfield will be and a panel south where buttons will be.Thats where i am putting a gridlayout to make the buttons.

BUT the problem coming across is that when i put in the text field, it doesn't show up on launch. But when i readjust the size manually of the window, it appears immediately. Does anyone know whats going on?

```
 public class calculator extends JFrame {

 public calculator() {
  super("Calculator");

  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  setSize(new Dimension(250,250));
    setVisible(true);


 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    calculator c = new calculator();
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.add(new JTextField(20));
    c.add(panel1,BorderLayout.NORTH);

 }

}
```

EDIT: SOLVED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class calculator extends JFrame {

    public calculator() {
        super("Calculator");    
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
        // setVisible(true); Wrong

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calculator c = new calculator();
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(new JTextField(20));
        c.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.setVisible(true); // Your components must be added before.
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, sorry im a newbie at this and still trying to learn. thanks alot

Comment: Thank you, you been a great help for a new guy to this website